# Converting plain text to dates

Tags: org-mode, time-date

Is it possible to convert plain text dates to Org dates automatically? I have entries in the format:

```
16 February 2015
```

which I would like to convert to Org dates: `<2015-02-16 Mon>`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Internally, `org-mode` uses the function `org-read-date` to do this:

```
(org-read-date &optional ORG-WITH-TIME TO-TIME FROM-STRING PROMPT
DEFAULT-TIME DEFAULT-INPUT INACTIVE)
```

For example,

```
(org-read-date nil nil "16 February 2015")
```

returns "2015-02-16".  This doesn't put in the "<>" or "[]" for active/inactive time-stamps, but you can easily add them with a format:

```
(format "<%s>"   (org-read-date nil nil "16 February 2015"))
```

Comment: And pressing `C-c c` on the result will add in the day of the week.

Comment: What would be an example of non nil ORG-WITH-TIME?

Answer (score 4):

I came up with something like this:

```
(defun my-format-time (time-string)
  (let* ((time (parse-time-string time-string))
         (day (nth 3 time))
         (month (nth 4 time))
         (year (nth 5 time)))
    (format-time-string "<%Y-%m-%d>" 
      ;; I would love to do an 'apply here, but the given list to be encoded contains nil which does n
      (encode-time 0 0 0 day month year))))
```

With that you can create an interactive function that scans for your specific date format and replaces the found date strings with the desired format.

For further reading have a look at:

http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/elisp_parse_time.html
http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Time-Parsing.html

Comment: Can you explain how to use this? I added `(interactive)` on the second line, selected date text and ran the function, but got an error about parameters.

Comment: @SabreWolfy You'll need to tell Emacs how to retrieve the time string, like with `(interactive "r")`